# Where can I find literature values for standard molar enthalpies of neutralization?

Tags: acid-base, thermodynamics, reference-request, databases

I'm looking for enthalpy of neutralization literature values for inorganic weak acids. NIST, PubChem, etc. don't list them. Is there somewhere else I should look?

Comment: I suspect this data might be somewhere in [JANAF thermochemical tables](https://janaf.nist.gov).

Comment: Doesn't look like it. Everything there is formation.

Comment: Try to discover the molar enthalpies of formation of 1) the ion H+ (or H3O+), 2) the ion OH-, and 3)  the liquid water. Take this last value, subtract first the enthalpy of formation of H+ and then the enthalpy of formation of OH-. And here you are. This gives you the molar enthalpiy of neutralization acid + base in solution. OK ?